# Xcode | Why use a launch screen file over launch images source?

Tags: ios, ios8, launch-screen

As far as I can tell these are two similar ways to do the same thing. If a launch screen file doesn't offer any advantages over a launch images source then why did Apple offer it? What am I missing?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This answer assumes you're talking about iOS, even though you didn't mention or tag iOS in your original question.

[A launch image](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html) is simply a static (non-changing) placeholder image.

"Launch Screen" (or more accurately "LaunchScreen" or "LaunchScreen.storyboard"), is the default name of the storyboard for a Launch Screen File; it is a *very simple* xib or storyboard file that appears before the rest of the app gets loaded up. The advantage to this is that a dev can use auto layout to reposition things subtly depending on the size of the screen (iPhone vs. iPad, iPhone 6 vs iPhone 6+, etc.).

Comment: do we need both value to be set ?  can I keep Launch Screen to blank ?

Answer (score 5):

You must use **Launch Screen File** if you want support iPhone 6 Plus or iPhone 6 according to [Apple's Doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/LaunchImages.html).

[image]

Comment: For iPhone 6+ - iOS 10, my app was working fine till last test flight build 15 days back. But now, when downloaded from Test flight,  while launching app. launch image is coming as app. icon which is enalarged and then my splash screen is loaded. This happens only on Test flight build.